# Not able to Crawl HTTPS web pages with Scrapy

Tags: python, django, scrapy, openssl, centos

I have a web **scraper** which works without any issues locally but it's not able to crawl HTTPS web pages on the production server (CentOS).

FYI. everything works as expected when I run the script through the command line (i.e. python scan.py) but I'm getting below errors when I run crawler from Django view.

I use the Apache webserver on CentOS. (Also, it works fine in my local Django setup)
I'm getting the below error when trying to crawl HTTPS web pages

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://validurl.com/>
```

Below is the full error log

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843638 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1658, in _inlineCallbacks
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843643 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     cast(Failure, result).throwExceptionIntoGenerator, gen
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843647 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 63, in run
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843652 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843656 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 500, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843660 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843664 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843669 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843672 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 55, in mustbe_deferred
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843675 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     result = f(*args, **kw)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843677 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 75, in download_request
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843680 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return handler.download_request(request, spider)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843683 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 65, in download_request
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843686 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return agent.download_request(request)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843689 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 335, in download_request
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843692 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     d = agent.request(method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843695 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1753, in request
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843698 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     endpoint = self._getEndpoint(parsedURI)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843700 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1737, in _getEndpoint
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843709 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return self._endpointFactory.endpointForURI(uri)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843712 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1609, in endpointForURI
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843715 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     uri.host, uri.port
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843718 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 67, in creatorForNetloc
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843720 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return ScrapyClientTLSOptions(hostname.decode("ascii"), self.getContext(),
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843723 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 64, in getContext
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843726 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     return self.getCertificateOptions().getContext()
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843729 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1632, in getContext
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843731 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     self._context = self._makeContext()
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843734 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1663, in _makeContext
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843737 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     ctx.set_verify(verifyFlags, _verifyCallback)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843739 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1084, in set_verify
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843742 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     self._verify_helper = _VerifyHelper(callback)
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843745 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]   File "/var/www/rocket/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 358, in __init__
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843747 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294]     "int (*)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *)", wrapper
[Wed Oct 20 08:55:14.843751 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 2291806:tid 139906821093120] [remote 91.204.188.11:55294] SystemError: <built-in method callback of CompiledFFI object at 0x7f3e83f31b28> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Below is the source code on how I call the **scraper** .

```
 def _start:
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(scanengine.SiteScanSpider, urls = [scan.project.url])
    process.start()
```

I run the crawler as a separate process from Django view.

```
p = Process(target=_start,args=(scan_id,))
p.start()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant source code.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I've added the source code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this particular crawler API, but from the code sample I suspect the issue may be related to trying to spawn a child process from a Django view, then the process or thread for the view is being terminated before the crawler completes causing a crash. You need to either:

1. Ensure the crawler is being run synchronously within the Django view. This may not be a great solution if the crawler has to run for more than a few seconds because of HTTP timeouts.
2. Or, just use the Django view to schedule a background task but not actually execute it. A Django model could potentially be [used as a queue](https://evanbyrne.com/blog/failure-tolerant-queue-django-postgresql/) or you could use something like Redis. Then execute the crawler in some sort of background process that is completely separate from the Django view. This could be done from a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/).